# SQL syntax error on nested if-else statements [mysql]

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have a following sql function where I am trying to use nested if-else statements.

The function is working fine with nested 'if' statement removed. But when added, the error is displayed.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE daysEntitled DECIMAL(4,2);
  DECLARE joinDate DATE;
  DECLARE dayOfMonth INT(4);
  SET joinDate = (SELECT join_date FROM users WHERE id = user);
  SET daysEntitled = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, joinDate, currentDate);
  IF YEAR(joinDate) = YEAR(currentDate) THEN
    SET currentDate = DATE_FORMAT(currentDate,'%Y-12-31');
    SET daysEntitled = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, joinDate, currentDate);
    SET dayOfMonth = CAST(DAY(joinDate) AS UNSIGNED);   

****** On adding this block ********

    IF dayOfMonth <= 15 THEN
       SET daysEntitled += 1.00;
    ENDIF;

****** On adding this block ********

  ELSEIF YEAR(joinDate) < YEAR(currentDate) THEN    
    SET daysEntitled = 8.00;    
  ELSEIF YEAR(joinDate) > YEAR(currentDate) THEN
    SET daysEntitled = 12.00;   
  ELSE
    SET daysEntitled = 4.00;  
  END IF;
  RETURN daysEntitled;
END
```

The code seems to be fine. I couldn't fine what went wrong.
Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having a nested `IF` statement in MySQL.  I think the problem is the way you are trying to increment the variable:

```
SET daysEntitled += 1.00;
                 ^^ not allowed
```

Use this code instead:

```
IF dayOfMonth <= 15 THEN
   SET daysEntitled = daysEntitled + 1.00;
ENDIF;
```